# Phusion Passenger + laravel error page show, All other routes are working except root url

Tags: laravel, passenger, phusion

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

Technical details for the administrator of this website Error ID: a4c93c83 Details: Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server.
Please read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error.

You can also get a detailed report to appear directly on this page, but for security reasons it is only provided if Phusion Passenger is run with environment set to development and/or with the friendly error pages option set to on.

For more information about configuring environment and friendly error pages, see:

Nginx integration mode
Apache integration mode
Standalone mode

This website is powered by Phusion Passenger®, the smart application server built by Phusion®.

I have clear all the cache for laravel, I have also upload my whole project again, But problem still exists